# Can't destroy current_user in functional test for sign_out method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, functional-testing, testunit

I want to test signin / signout methods with this test:

**test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb**

```
class SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  fixtures :users
  include SessionsHelper

  test "should signin and signout" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
    post :create, email: users(:alex).email, password: 'qwerty'
    assert_redirected_to profile_url
    assert cookies[:remember_token]
    assert current_user == users(:alex), 'Ooops! Wrong current_user!'

    delete :destroy
    assert_redirected_to signin_url
    debugger
    assert !cookies[:remember_token]
 => assert !current_user, 'Ooops! Current_user not nil!'
  end
end
```

In **=>** point `cookies[:remember_token]` is gone, but `current_user` still `users(:alex)`, and I don't understand why. Did I missed smth in `delete :destroy` line?
Integrations tests are passing and live performance in browser with sign-out act also do the trick.

Methods from sessions controller and helper:

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
def destroy
  sign_out
  redirect_to signin_url
end
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end

def sign_out
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  self.current_user = nil
end
```

Comment: What does `User.find_by( remember_token: User.encrypt( nil ) )` return?

Comment: `User.find_by(remember_token: User.encrypt(nil)) => nil`

Answer (score 1):

I'm less familiar with Rails than Sinatra, but shouldn't the `SessionsHelper` be included via the `helpers` method in the controller already?

Including the `SessionsHelper` module directly in the test means you now have two classes with `@current_user` and associated methods - the controller class, and the test class.

So the `destroy` method on the controller route deals with its copy, whilst the test gets it's own (which it conveniently populates from the database via the shared the cookie value). The controller's `destroy` method does not alter the instance variable in the test object.

The test probably should not make assertions about the `current_user` value directly, but rely on data that it can extract from the web server responses. You should not have `include SessionsHelper` in this test (in a unit test for the helper it would be OK).

Comment: If I don't have this include, then test don't know what `current_user` is. So how can I test cookie-part and current_user-part in my test?

Comment: @Alex Fedoseev: There is no requirement for a test of a controller to "know" what the server has stored internally as the current_user variable. Test for behaviour of the site. E.g. for log out, check 1) what the web page now calls you, 2) whether you are offered to "log in" or "log out", 3) that you cannot access private resources.

Comment: If you want to test the `current_user` method, create a unit test for the `SessionsHelper` module. I.e. you need two tests here for the two layers in the application.